# How to create a text box to print text when button is pressed

Tags: java, button, textbox, popup

I'm very new to Java. I'm trying to create a text box appear to print an array I have made. I'm not sure what to write or how to go about it?

Any help would be great.

Comment: Please share what you have written so far.

Comment: Its a bit long what I have written, I would just like a simple example of how I would go about to display the text. I have named the button btn1 and the array Is called singleTest

Comment: Look up basic Swing tutorials.

Comment: What do you mean by "print an array"? An array of what? Integers? Strings? Pixmaps? What do you want the outcome to look .like? Everything on one line? Multiple lines? Column oriented? What kind of font?

Comment: Its an array of integers 'textbox.setText(singleTest);' Im not sure if that is correct but I want a button to be pressed and when its pressed the array called singleTest to printed in it.?

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/swing/swing_action_listener.htm

Comment: Do you need it in Swing or JavaFx?

Comment: It was in Swing, however, I have found out how to print it but it's just not in the format I need it. Is there a way to limit the number of characters in a line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add an `ActionListener` to your button. This will allow you to do things when it is pressed.

```
JButton button = new JButton();
JTextField textField = new JTextField();

button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt)
    {
       //set text to whatever in array probably in for loop
       textField.setText( getArrayValues(array) );
    }
});

...

public String getArrayValues(int[] array)
{
   String value = new String();
   for(int i = 0; i < array.length-1; i++)
   {
      value += i + ", ";
   }
   value += i;
   return value;
}
```

Comment: This helped, it worked for me. Got it working in the end through some trial and error :)

Answer (score 0):

you should have something like this:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setSize(300, 300);
frame.setLayout(null);
JTextField field = new JtextField();
field.setBounds(10, 10, width, height)
field.setText(Arrays.toString(yourArray));
frame.add(field);
```

for setting the text by pressing the button, see Orin's answer

Comment: OP wants the text to appear only when a button is pressed. This code will display the array without a button press.

Comment: I can only see this text:
I'm very new to Java. I'm trying to create a text box appear to print an array I have made. I'm not sure what to write or how to go about it?

Any help would be great.

Comment: Question title: "How to create a text box to print text when button is pressed"

Comment: ah ok then, I'll edit my answer

Comment: Thank you to everyone that commented and helped out, got it working in the end with the help of Orin2005 and some trial and error. :)